# Get cluster size

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, volume

I am working on an upper volume filter driver taking diskperf as base.
I want to know how can I calculate cluster size(allocation unit size).
I know that using `GetDiskFreeSpace` I can get the desired output, but it's useful only in user mode.
I want it to work at the kernel level.
Is there any IOCTL or any function that will help me to find the cluster size?

Comment: Did you try seeing if you can look at the source of `GetDiskFreeSpace()`? It should be making IOCTL calls itself.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, where can I get the source of GetDiskFreeSpace()?

Answer (score 1):

`ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile/NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with FsInformationClass set to `FILE_FS_SIZE_INFORMATION` struct.

Or use [IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff549318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thanks Xearinox, Can you provide me any example or sample or any link that illustrates the use of `IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION` or `ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile/NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with upper volume filter driver because I tried to search for the example of `IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION` with upper volume but I did not got any kind of help.